# BEA-382501 Business service returns unrecognized response to Proxy service

Tags: oracle12c, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-service-bus

I know that my question is probably a duplicate, but I'm stuck.

I have a REST business service that sends POST to and endpoint. Testing it works fine with a 200 response.

My Pipeline execute a service call out, that in return gets a 200 response from the endpoint, but returns a BEA-382501 fault to the pipeline.

"Use Chunked Streaming Mode" is disabled!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to enable XOP/MTOM support in business service.
It was working when I tried request directly thru bs, but I was unable to send message thru service callout to bs

Comment: How can one enable it? 
I cannot find it under BS's properties.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your pipeline is not properly configured to handle the response message.

I can't comment yet so I will have to ask you this way. Can you check your diagnostic log and see what exactly happens during the flow of your message?

diagnostic log can be found: Enterprise manager -> Weblogic Domain dropdown menu (right top) -> Logs -> view log messages -> Target log files (top right) -> Last modified. It should be named like "server_1-diagnostic.log".

Make sure execution tracing is enabled for this pipeline. You can find this in Enterprise manager too.

Comment: No error in the log files. look legit.